# POST-запрос через Postman срабатывает, а через библиотеку requests нет

Tags: python, веб-программирование, http, requests

Есть Python-код:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
proxies = {"http":"http://127.0.0.1:8080", "https":"http://127.0.0.1:8080"}
```

Следующие 2 запроса (POST и GET) срабатывают успешно

```
def connect():
    url = 'http://example.com/site/ajax-login'
    r = session.get(url)
    payload = {
               'LoginForm[method]':'ga' , 
               'LoginForm[password]':'password' , 
               'LoginForm[email]':'email@mail.com', 
               'LoginForm[codeTwoFactorAuthentication]':'TFACode'
              }
    data = session.post(url, proxies=proxies, data = payload)
    print(data.text)

def get_list():
    url = 'http://example.com/another/api/list?type=1&money=USD&lang=ru&auth_id=1'
    req = session.get(url)
    print(req.text)
```

Но вот этот запрос возвращает 500 Internal Server Error, хотя в Postman возвращает 200 и success.

```
def confirm_payment(code):
    url = 'http://example.com/one/more/api/change'
    payload = {
               'id':'3',
               'status':'4',
               'code':'{}'.format(code),
               'method':'ga',
               'im_check':'1'
              }
    req = session.post(url, data=payload, proxies=proxies)
    print(req.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
    get_list()
    confirm_payment(33)
```

Ответ, который приходит при отправке запроса

[image: Ответ, который приходит при выполнении запроса]

Вопрос: Почему срабатывает в Postman, а через requests нет?

Comment: Нужно вам узнать какjq postman отправляет запрос. Мб какие-нибудь заголовки нужно заполнять. А чтобы увидеть какой запрос отправляет `requests`, добавьте этот код: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/257e7549078edb6571f3704048ea099010faa4fd/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10 . Кст, а последний запрос случаем не JSON требует, тогда нужно вместо `data=` указывать `json=`, вот так: `session.post(url, json=payload, proxies=proxies)`, это важно

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `req = session.post(url, data=payload, proxies=proxies)` нужно не `data=` использовать, а `json=`:

```
req = session.post(url, json=payload, proxies=proxies)
```

Разница будет в сформированном заголовке запроса.

Для `data=` заголовок [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Content-Type) будет `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, а для `json=` -- `application/json`

Поэтому, у сервера и была внутренняя ошибка: `500 Internal Server Error`